# Can't clear session variables in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel session class to set session variables.when i tried to clear those variables, it didn't worked. I have used the following code to unset variables.

```
    Auth::logout();
    Session::forget();
    Session::flush();
    session_destroy();
    unset(Session::all());
```

None of these code worked.any help will be appreciated... thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$request->session()->flush();
```

have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session)

Answer (score 0):

have to specify sesssion key in forget method.
`Session::forget('key');`